# Complex fractions

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators, mathtools

How to make this more adequate ('beatifuller' :))? 2 needs to be better shown as being in the power of n-1, but the current representation just smothers it.

`\frac{1}{1-\sum_{2}^{n} \frac{1}{{\frac{r}{R}}^(2^(n-1))}}`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\frac{1}{1-\sum_{2}^{n} \frac{1}{{\frac{r}{R}}^(2^(n-1))}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one more variation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{1}{1-\sum\limits_{2}^{n} \Bigl(\mfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^{\! -2^{n-1}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to write *a*<sup>*bc*</sup>, you need to write `a^{bc}` instead of `a^bc` or `a^(bc)`. I prefer this way

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{1}{1-\sum_{2}^{n}\cfrac{1}{\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^{2^{n-1}}}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I propose one of these, based on the medium-size commands from `nccmath` (~ 80% of `\displaystyle`):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{1}{1-\medop\sum_{2}^{n} \frac{1}{\bigl(\mfrac{r}{R}\bigr)^{\! 2^{n-1\mathstrut}}}} \qquad \frac{1}{1-\medop\sum_{2}^{n} \bigl(\mfrac{R}{r}\bigr)^{\!2^{n-1}}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]